# Python Help needed : Unable to read contents of a tsv file and populate in the dictionary as desired

Tags: python, text-parsing

## What i have to parse :

I have a tsv file that looks like this : 
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxsXD.png

## What is the end goal:

My goal is to read the tsv file and populate the contents of the csv file in a dictionary and nested lists without using csv parser.

In the end the `in_memory_table` structure would look 
like this ( of course with more than two rows ):

{

```
 "header": [
    "STATION",
    "STATION_ID",
    "ELEVATION",
    "LAT",
    "LONG",
    "DATE",
    "MNTH_MIN",
    "MNTH_MAX"
],

"rows": [
    [
        "Tukwila",
        "12345afbl",
        "10",
        "47.5463454",
        "-122.34234234",
        "2016-01-01",
        "10",
        "41"
    ],
    [
        "Tukwila",
        "12345afbl",
        "10",
        "47.5463454",
        "-122.34234234",
        "2016-02-01",
        "5",
        "35"
    ],
]
```

}

## My code looks like this:

```
in_memory_table = {
'header': [],
'rows': []      }

with open('fahrenheit_monthly_readings.tsv') as f:
in_file = f.readlines()

i = 0
for line in in_file:
    temp_list = [line.split('\t')]

    if (i == 0):
        in_memory_table['header']= line

    elif(i != 0):
       in_memory_table['rows'].append(line)

    i += 1



print("\n",in_memory_table)
```

## Output of the code:

C:\Users\svats\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/svats/PycharmProjects/BrandNew/module4_lab2/module4_lab2.py

```
 {'header': 'STATION\tSTATION_ID\tELEVATION\tLAT\tLONG\tDATE\tMNTH_MIN\tMNTH_MAX\n', 'rows': ['Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-01-01\t10\t41\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-02-01\t5\t35\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-03-01\t32\t47\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-04-01\t35\t49\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-05-01\t41\t60\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-06-01\t50\t72\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-07-01\t57\t70\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-08-01\t68\t79\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-09-01\t55\t71\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-10-01\t47\t77\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-11-01\t32\t66\n', 'Tukwila\t12345afbl\t10\t47.5463454\t-122.34234234\t2016-12-01\t27\t55\n']}
```

## Help needed:

i am very close towards getting the solution 
I have 2 questions :

```
1. how to get rid of the \t in the o/p?
2. My o/p is little different from the desired o/p. how do i get it ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite your code as:

```
for line in in_file:
    print('repr(line) before :', repr(line) )
    temp_list = [line.split()]
    #line = line.split()
    print('temp_list :',temp_list)
    print('repr(line) after  :', repr(line) )
    print(' %s -----------------' % i)

    if ........
```

and de-comment the line  `#line = line.split()`
you'll understand the reason of the bad result you obtain.

The reason is that `line.split()` doesn't change the object of name `line` ,
it creates a new object (the list you want) to which name `line` must be re-assigned if you want this name to refer to the obtained list.

Note that the method **str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])** has a different algorithm according if parameter `sep` is `None` or not `None`, see documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split for this point

.

That said, there's a better way.

```
with open('fahrenheit_monthly_readings.tsv','r') as f:
    in_memory_table = {'header':next(f).split()}
    in_memory_table['rows'] = [line.split() for line in f]
```

or

```
with open('fahrenheit_monthly_readings.tsv','r') as f:
    in_memory_table = {'header':next(f).split()}
    in_memory_table['rows'] = list(map(str.split, f))
```

Comment: The first half of your response solved my problem. Instead of assigning line to the dictionary headers, i assigned temp_list and it worked like a charm..Thanks again for your pointer....much appreciated..